# Display Axios reponse - TypeError: this.state.cryptos.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new to React and am running into a problem trying to display the response from the axios request. Here is the error I am getting when loading the component `TypeError: this.state.cryptos.map is not a function`

Here is my react component:

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios"
import CryptoCurrency from '../presentationals/CryptoCurrency'

class CryptoView extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { cryptos: [] };
      }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT,LOOM,EOS&tsyms=USD')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                this.setState({cryptos: res.data});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        const cryptocurrencies = this.state.cryptos.map((crypto, index) =>
        <CryptoCurrency
          key = { index }
          title = { crypto.title }
          subtitle = {crypto.subtitle }
          image = { crypto.image }
        />
      )
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Crypto View Screen </h1>
                <Link to="../">Back</Link>
                {cryptocurrencies}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CryptoView
```

Sorry if this is a really easy error that I am missing, I can't seem to solve the problem and move on. I did not provide the code for the CryptoCurrency presentational component since it doesn't seem to have anything to do with it but I can provide it if necessary

Comment: `res.data` does not seem to be an array. Can you check if the response has the expected shape? The code looks okay and should be working if `res.data` is actually an array.

Comment: oh, I see. I will look into that thanks

Comment: Realized it was because I was treating the response as an array rather than an object (thanks to @trixn). This is how i answered it const cryptocurrencies = Object.keys(this.state.cryptos).map((key, index) =>
        <CryptoCurrency
          key = { index }
          ticker = { key }
          price = { this.state.cryptos[key].USD}
        />
 )

Comment: It should be noted that iterating over an object's keys or entries has no guaranteed order. Do not expect it to be ordered alphabetically. In fact there could be a different order during two subsequent iterations over the same object. So if a certain order is required make sure to sort the keys or entries before iterating over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are calling returns an object, not an array.

So you have `this.state.cryptos` being:

```
cryptos = {
  "BTC": {
    "USD": 6766.97
  },
  "ETH": {
    "USD": 278.22
  },
  "IOT": {
    "USD": 0.5418
  },
  "LOOM": {
    "USD": 0.09514
  },
  "EOS": {
    "USD": 5.05
  }
}
```

I'd recommend you use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to deal with it

```
Object.entries(cryptos).map(crypto => {
  console.log(crypto[0]) // BTC, ETH...
  console.log(crypto[1]) //​​​​​{ USD: 6766.97 }, ​​​​​{ USD: 278.22 }...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What Cohars has mentioned is absolutely right.

Few things I want to clarify interms of making you understand better about when to use map.

You can use map when your array contains list of object. Map works on array so this.state.xxx.map is not a function meaning it’s not an object.

If it is an object but not an array of objects then you can us Object.entries or Object.keys too to do iteration.

You should understand that difference. Though it is theatrical hope the concept explains.

Comment: Agreed and understood. Thanks for explaining that in detail.